# Доступ к изображениям основного домена из поддомена

Tags: домен, поддомены

Здравствуйте!

Проблема: 
при обращении с поддомена m.xxx.ru к изображению которое находится на основном домене то собственно изображение не отображается в скрипте поддомена (но есть доступ к именам всех фотографий в директории). К примеру если обратиться из m.xxx.ru к файлу на основном домене xxx.ru/news/12/01.jpg (через относительный путь ../xxx.ru/news/12/01.jpg) изображение не отображается но скрипт видит все названия файлов в каталоге news. Быть может на сервере стоит какое либо ограничение которое не позволяет в полной мере общаться домену с поддоменом? Спасибо.

Comment: скрипт видит все названия файлов в каталоге news - или в каталоге news/12?

Comment: Пишите абсолютный путь, и все получится.

Comment: спринт видит названия  в каталоге news/12.  Если использовать абсолютный путь тогда почему то не работает выборка через @opendir('http://xxx.ru/news/12/').

Comment: можно только гадать о вашем скрипте, не видя его и даже не зная языка, на котором он написан.

Comment: Скрипт то он наверняка и не причем, так так не работает даже простой вывод в тег <img src="../xxx.ru/news/19/01.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">     структура сервера /home/x/data/www/m.xxx.ru/  основной домен так же в каталоге www

Comment: а если в http:// начать все-таки?

Comment: вот эта вот хреновина не принимает если указать http:// впервые с такой ерундой сталкиваюсь |                            $dir_handle = @opendir('http:// - путь ') or die("No image in directory1!");
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
    $file_parts = explode('.', $file);
    $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_parts));
    $title = implode('.', $file_parts);
    $title = htmlspecialchars($title);
    $files_names_p[$i] = $file; 
    $nomargin = '';
    $i++;
}

Comment: Значит PHP все-таки. Путь на сервере тоже не пробовали писать?

Comment: Извиняюсь, я скорее всего не особо внятно все объясняю. Может показаться странным но задаю вопрос на этом ресурсе впервые, в основном ищу ответы.  Путь на сервере?. Может мне тупо поддомен создать в корневом каталоге основного домена, потом тоже свои нюансы. Похоже нужно закрывать этот вопрос (:

Comment: путь типа var/home/user/domain_name

Comment: Пробовал, такая же мистика. Имя изображения читает а саму картинку не показывает